# How can I achieve fluid width video?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I tried using the example for fluid width video and it works for the video but other typ of content (plain text comment) should not have the padding and now they get they padding resulting in a large gap of nothing with each comment that is not a video. Can you tell me how I can fix the layout so that all elements are fluid and responsive?

```
.abstract{

}

.abstract-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.abstract-inner iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="abstract-container">

        <div class="abstract">
          <div class="abstract-inner">

              <iframe width="512" height="288" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r9yH-EmnGX4?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

          </div>
          </div>



      </div>
```

The above is just a fragment, but I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/6f783nns/1/) if it helps. Maybe you know what I should do to make the video have a fluid responsiveness and the text properly placed?

If I use only this CSS, then everything is fins except the height of the video that is too small:

```
.abstract{

}

.abstract-inner {

}
.abstract-inner iframe{

   min-width: 100% !important;
   max-width: 100% !important;
   min-height: 100% !important;
   max-height:100% !important;
}
```

If I use CSS viewport units then the page looks right in the fiddle but combined with my other code then the video get blown up larger than the page.

[image]

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/6f783nns/9/) the problem is reproduced using CSS viewports when the page is resized to fit also the menu to the left.

Comment: There is no input box. What text are you talking about, using the latest version of Chrome all of the text looks properly placed

Comment: @doveyg Thank you for the comment. I have updated the question and the fiddle so that it becomes more clear. There is no input box, it was about some other question that was left from my typing. Now the updated fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/6f783nns/3/

Comment: Like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6f783nns/5/)

Comment: @doveyg it looks right but I can't remove the classes from the text comments. I don't have a way to adjust the CSS classes which are the same for the video and the text. I'm glad you understood the problem though.

Comment: So what can you change? Why cant you change the HTML?

Comment: I can only change the CSS because the list of content is dynamically generated. The answer about using CSS viewport units is close but when I use it the video blows up to very large propertion.

Comment: Well, you can change the HTML. Have your code detect when media is embedded and wrap it in that container `<div>`.

Comment: Do you realize that if you embed multiples of youtube videos that you are going to see the same problem? You will also see a problem if you change the element placement and arrangement. From the screenshot you provided it looks like a fixed pixel design.

Comment: @doveyg Thank you for the comments. I understand what you mean with changing the HTML but we want a pure CSS solution and I found that it is the menu to the left that is breaking the layout. When the menu to the left is included then the video becomes too large if I use the CSS viewports.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [CSS viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) in this case.

The code also becomes a lot simpler. (You may also find that some of the wrapper elements aren't necessary anymore)

```
iframe {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 56.25vw; /* 16:9 ... 56.25vw means 56.25% of the viewport width*/
}
```

That's it.

### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/6f783nns/8/) (Resize to verify that the iframe keeps aspect ratio)

**NB:**

If you only want the iframe to take up a certain % of the viewport width (say 80% ) - this can still be done while still maintaining the correct aspect ratio on the iframe .

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jz0hz1pg/3/) (Resize the viewport width)

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56.25vw;
  /* 16:9 ... 56.25vw means 56.25% of the viewport width*/
}
aside {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: aqua;
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  aside {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  iframe {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 45vw;
    /* 9/16 * 80 = 45  */
  }
  .content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .wpr {
    display: table;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <aside>blabla</aside>
  <div class="content">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r9yH-EmnGX4?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    <p>content here</p>
    <p>content here</p>
    <p>content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks right in the fiddle but if I use it with my larger code base then the video get blown up very large. I don't know why. I tried adding all my stylesheets to the fiddle but I couldn't reproduce the problem. I updated my question with a screenshot how it looks. I can not yet reproduce it with the fiddle. I think that CSS viewport units is right to use but for some reason it blows up the video like shown from my screenshot.

Comment: try using `width: 100vw;` as well on the iframe

Comment: I edited the fiddle to include all my page then it shows that it is the left menu that conflict in some way because when the fiddle is resized to include the menu on the left then the video if blown out of proportion. http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/6f783nns/9/

Comment: The menu to the left is 248px wide and when it is collapsed due to resizing then the viewport unit solution seems to work. We need to adjust the viewport solution to work when the page has the left menu which is 248 px wide.

Comment: hmmm that code is rather complex. As far as I know in order to use viewport units successfully in your case - you'll have to set the width of the menu as a % of the viewport - not in px. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jz0hz1pg/3/) which uses media queries to show the menu only if the viewport width is > 900px. It should be enough to get you going.

Comment: I updated the answer with the new fiddle which uses media queries

Comment: Thank you but the `display: table-cell;` breaks my left margin. I think that CSS viewport is right to use but as usual with CSS nothing is possible if you want a small change. I've been stuck on this for days without a plan and without a solution.

Comment: the `display: table-cell;` is only an example. The menu and iframe can be set inline using many different methods such as `display:inline-block` or `float:left` etc

Comment: I don't think I should have to start over from the beginning just because I want responsive video. Now I have more than 3 problems just because I wanted responsive elements.

Comment: fluidity is not something that can be easily turned on and off, the HTML has to suit the needs of the design. We all make unnecessary elements to achieve a design or look. This is just another example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do similar thing like this

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
      updateiframeSize()
    };

function updateiframeSize() {
    $(".abstract-inner").each(function(){
        $this = jQuery(this);
        var ratio_cont = $this.width()/$this.height();
        var $iframe = $this.find("iframe");
        var ratio_iframe= $iframe.width()/$iframe.height();
        if (ratio_cont > ratio_iframe)
        {
            $iframe.css({"width": "100%", "height": "auto"});
        }
        else if (ratio_cont < ratio_img)
        {
            $iframe.css({"width": "auto", "height": "100%"});
        }
    }); 
};
```

if you want in css try

```
iframe{
  width: 100%    !important;
  height: auto   !important;
}
```

> if you want to keep aspect ratio then put width:100% and height:auto
>
> if you want to cover whole parent element then height:100% and width:100%